# Error : set an Environment variable JAVA_HOME to point to it?

Tags: android

I am trying to plug-in android in to my laptop 
Configuration: vista OS, 64 bit and RAM 4GB
I install the Eclipse, JDK 7 and installer_r18_windows.exe file from android site. when I try to run the windows installer it shows the message

**Error:Failed to find the java version for C:\Windows\System32\java.exe: the system cannot find the file specified.** and at last
**if you believe you have a JDK installed and it was not properly recognized,simply set an environment variable JAVA_HOME to point to it**

I don't know how to set an environment variable. How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Step 1**
Make sure You have installed Java 64 bit version

**Step2 copy c:\windows\system32\java.exe to c:\windows\syswow64**

And last to learn How to set Environment Variables here you go

http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Last Thing

If you are installing 32bit java version
Installation path will be

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin

If you are installing 64but java version 
Installation path will be

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin

So set this path in Environment variables.

Comment: I have one doubt about the installed path for the development kit. I gave the downloads path but it went wrong

Comment: I am using the jdk 7.I used your 64 bit java version code,I changed...C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin... to ...C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin..but not working ,the same problem. let me install JDK 6

Comment: Thanks Vipul for your valuable reply ..it is now OK .